# Import inner interface of parent class by child class package qualifier

Tags: java, inheritance, import, inner-classes

I have 2 classes like this:

Parent class A:

```
public class A {   
  public interface A2 {
  }
}
```

Child class B:

```
public class B extends A {
}
```

And when I use the inner interface of A:

```
import com.company.A.A2;         //statement 1
import com.company.B.A2;         //statement 2 -> error here!

//...
com.company.A.A2 a21;            //statement 3
com.company.B.A2 a22;            //statement 4
```

All the statements are valid except the one I marked (**statement 2**). I wonder:

- Why I can declare using fully qualifier "**com.company.B.A2**" as **statement 4** but I cannot import it by using **statement 2**?

PS:
I know that com.company.A.A2 & com.company.A.A2 are 2 alias of exact 1 class.

- If Java allows statement 4, it should allow statement 2
- If Java does not allow statement 4 ,it should not allow statement 4,
  too
- I think it's really ambiguous if Java allows statement 4 valid.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @GhostCat Cannot resolve symbol A2...

Comment: Static elements are not inherited.

Comment: @chrylis I know, but pls read my wonder, I can use fully qualifier but cannot import

Answer (score 1):

[JLS 6.7, Fully Qualified Names and Canonical Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7) (snipped)

> Each member class, member interface, and array type *may* have a fully qualified name:
>
> - A member class or member interface M of another class or interface C has a fully qualified name if and only if C has a fully qualified name.
>
>   In that case, the fully qualified name of M consists of the fully qualified name of C, followed by ".", followed by the simple name of M.

> Each member class, member interface, and array type may have a canonical name:
>
> - A member class or member interface M declared in another class or interface C has a canonical name if and only if C has a canonical name.
>
>   In that case, the canonical name of M consists of the canonical name of C, followed by ".", followed by the simple name of M.

Example 6.7-2 specifically notes that both `*.A.A2` and `*.B.A2` in your example are FQNs for the interface, but that only `*.A.A2` is the *canonical* name because that is where `A2` is *declared*.

[JLS 7.5, Import Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5)

> - A single-type-import declaration (§7.5.1) imports a single named type, by mentioning its canonical name (§6.7).